# Converting user input strings with Special characters to regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Note: there was a similar question but since it didn't have 'Special characters' and the problem here is only with 'Special characters', I posted a new question.

I have a list (from user input textarea) of Regular Expression representations:

Example: (simplified)

```
// starting point is a string like this one
let str = `/ab+c/
/Chapter (\d+)\.\d*/
/\d+/
/d(b+)d/`;
```

I need to convert them into an array to check (for validity) and prepare each line e.g. (simplified)

```
let arr = str.split(/[\r\n]+/);

for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {

  arr[i] = arr[i].slice(1, -1); // removing the start/end slashes
  // problem with double slashing the Special characters
  // it doesn't give the required result
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\\/g, '\\$&');
  // same result with replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
}
```

Finally, convert them into one RegEx object

```
let regex = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'i'); 

console.log(regex.test('dbbbd')); // true
console.log(regex.test('256')); // false
```

I must be missing something here.

**Update**
**I missed the point that the data that comes from a textarea (or similar) doesn't need to be escaped at all. When I was testing the code, I was testing it like above which didn't work.**

Comment: RegExp objects are not string type. First you have to do like `/\d+/.toString();` or use type coercion like `myRegExpObj + ""` and then perform string operations.

Comment: Since the strings are already regular expressions, you just don’t need to replace anything. You would need to do so only if you wanted special characters to be matched literally, which is not the case here.

Comment: From where do you receive this string of regexps..? I guess if the string is thought to represent regexps then all \ characters should have been escaped like \\ to start with.

Comment: *If you check, they are already strings and not objects.* They are either strings or regexp objects (aka normal regexp). If the regexps are represented by a template literal just like in your example... then the "\" characters must be escaped like "\\"

Comment: Then you have to check entered characters like `mytextArea.addEventListener("keydown", checkForBackslash)` so that when user enters a "\" you can manually escape it. You may try like `chr = chr === "\" ? "\\" : chr`

Comment: @erosman no, `new RegExp()` doesn’t need double \ if you actually want the regular expression meaning (e.g `\d` for digits). It’s the string literal that needs it, because \ is used there for some escape sequences such as `\n` and quite a few more. Do in your original code, you should have \\ in the string, but not manipulate it afterwards. If the regex comes from somewhere else (HTML input, JSON...) then you don’t need to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets use the `"change"` event on `<textarea>` so that once the user changes the content and clicks outside, we just access the `value` property of it we can then construct the composite RegExp object. I haven't had the need to escape the `\` characters at all.

Just copy paste the following to the text area and click outside.

```
/ab+c/
/Chapter (\d+)\./
/\d+/
/d(b+)d/
```

```js
var myTextarea = document.getElementById("ta");

myTextarea.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var str = e.currentTarget.value.split(/[\r\n]+/)
                                 .map(s => s.slice(1, -1))
                                 .join("|");
      rgx = new RegExp(str, "i")
  console.log(`Derived RegExp object: ${rgx}`);
  console.log(`Testing for 'dbbbd': ${rgx.test('dbbbd')}`); // true
  console.log(`Testing for '256': ${rgx.test('256')}`);     // true
});
```

```css
#ta {
  width: 33vw;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-left: 33vw;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

Comment: @erosman I showed it in `<textarea>` since you have mentioned it in one of your comments. It works well with `<textarea>` and `'256'` returns `true` in the above code. Could you please tell me from where exactly this string is originated..?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. The data from textarea works without the need to escape it but it doesn't work when I try it is a code string :(

Comment: @erosman I understand `<textarea>` "automatically" escapes the special characters so that when we `console.log()` it's `value` property the string looks normal. You can store that string in the `localStorage` and retrieve and it will be kept the same. So when you construct a string manually in your code from scratch, you should add \ characters by doing `myText + "\\"` or by `myText + String.fromCharCode(92)`. On the other hand, any string that you receive from an API call, if looks proper when you `console.log()`, has already escaped backslashes just like a string from `<textarea>`.

Comment: You are correct.... and I missed that completely. :p I was testing using string literals instead of testing using the real situation and therefore I missed it. I also missed the point that textarea, input, & storage data are not process as string literals even after getting assigned to a variable. Sorry for my confusion.